# Term for the text editor feature to have fixed pages

Tags: microsoft-word, visual-studio, pdf-reader

PDF viewers and word documents are separated by pages.  If you wanted to, you can view page by page like a book.

For coding purposes, I think it'd be more efficient for me to see code like that- page by page.  So when I press page down, I can expect a consistent view of the code already there, but possibly lowered down a little because of the code above.

The main focus is down is to restrict the pages so I cannot scroll down line by line-- I have to scroll page by page.

I don't know if it is more efficient, but I'd certainly like to give it a try.

Is there a way to do it in Visual Studio?

Comment: you mean like what you get with the page down and page up buttons?

Comment: Right, but specify the page up/page down to say...  Always go to Line 40, 80, 120, or whatever the closest increment is.

Comment: The idea is that if I went to a certain line, I'd be able to recognize where my functions are immediately, since my view is consistent.